# Pulsating glow effect on .png logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do make a pulsating-glowing-effect on a logo. First I tried to solve it with CSS and some jquery snippets, but this has just effect on the rectangle of the image and not on the image itself inside the rectangle.

Does anyone have a solution e.g. with html5? Unfortunately i'am not very skilled on html5. Does anyone have an example i could have a look at?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If it's a png with transparent background then it shouldn't matter what the boundaries are right?

Comment: @elclanrs they actually matter, even if the png is transparent CSS is not Photoshop, the effects are applied on the box model. The img tag itself it's a rectangle , even if it's transparent.
The solution is like pointed by Rob Hardy, to have a second image. I could code one in JSfiddle if you can't handle it. You should just use a setInterval in javascript and switch the img each time.

Comment: @AvnerSolomon: Oh I see, you're right. Misunderstood the question...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by having 2 logo images. 1 without the glow and 1 with.

Place them one over the other an fade the glowing image in and out using JQuery animation on the opacity.

Sorry, I don't know of an example, but this should work.

Comment: Or even easier, just a gif with all of the animations in it ;)

Comment: A gif would work, but you would be bound to a 256 color pallet and no variable opacity. Many find this restrictive and it can't be used to create attractive high quality graphics.

Comment: You'd also have to store the fading as individual frame in the GIF so the GIF option is likely going to be a much larger performance burden

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with CSS, a property called drop-shadow and a filter

```
@-webkit-keyframes redPulse {
    from { -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px rgba(194,0,0,0.7)); filter: url(shadow.svg#drop-shadow); }
    50% { -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px rgba(255,0,0,1)); filter: url(shadow.svg#drop-shadow); }
    to { -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px rgba(194,0,0,0.7)); filter: url(shadow.svg#drop-shadow); }
}
.myimage {
    width: 500px;
}
.glow { 
    -webkit-animation-name: redPulse;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

You have to add glow and myimage to the class of img tag to make a glow *red*.

myimage is to set the width of the image and glow is an animation in webkit with the drop-shadow property and a filter. Try it!

Comment: I believe this would add a glow to the outer part of the image--not the outer part of the logo that is a part of the image.

Comment: Too early.it It works great in Chrome, but not in IE and Safari and FF.

Comment: `-webkit` css attributes are specific to webkit based browsers.

Comment: Right. Really impressive in Chrome, but not efficient enough if it just works there.